# How to use VirtualBox API to log into a Windows VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to use the VirtualBox COM API to start Windows VMs from a snapshot. When the VM starts it displays the Ctl-Alt-Delete screen. Does the API provide a way to log into a Windows box? I know I could take the snapshots from a running image where I'm already logged in but I'd prefer not to do this.

My host is 64-bit Windows 7 and the VMs will be a range of OS versions from 32-bit Win 2003 to Win 2012. My programming language is C# 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keyboard.PutCAD();

For example:

```
    bool SendCtlAltDel(IMachine machine)
    {
        var session = new Session();
        try {
            machine.LockMachine(session, LockType.LockType_Shared);
            IConsole console = session.Console;

            IKeyboard keyboard = console.Keyboard;
            keyboard.PutCAD(); // Send Ctrl-Alt-Del
        } catch (Exception e) {
            IConsole console = session.Console;
            Console.WriteLine("Console state = {0}", console.State);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (session.State == SessionState.SessionState_Locked)
                session.UnlockMachine();
        }

        return true;
    }
```